# How is the correct way to handle MySQL connections in Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I built a program with NodeJS where multiple users access it in the same time and do a lot of operations that queries the MySQL database.

My approach is very simple. I only open one connection when the app is started and leave it that way.

```
const dbConfig = require('./db-config');
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Create mySQL Connection
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: dbConfig.host,
    user: dbConfig.user,
    password: dbConfig.password,
    database: dbConfig.database,
    multipleStatements: true
});

// Connect MySQL
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log('MySQL connected!');
    }
});

module.exports = db;
```

And then, whenever the program needs to query the database, i do like this

```
db.query('query_in_here', (error, result) => {
         *error_handling_and_doing_stuff*
}
```

I'm having trouble when noone access the app for a long period of time (some hours).

Because when this happens i think the connection is being closed automatically. And then, when a user try to access the app, i see in the console that the connection timed out.

My first thought was too handle the disconnection and connect again. But, it get me thinking if this is the correct approach.

Should i use pool connections instead? Because if i keep only one connection it means that two users can't query the database in the same time?

I tried to understand tutorials with pool connections but couldn't figure out when to create new connections and when should i end them.

**UPDATE 1**

Instead of create one connection when the app is started i changed to create a pool connection.

```
const dbConfig = require('./db-config');
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Create mySQL Connection
const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: dbConfig.host,
    user: dbConfig.user,
    password: dbConfig.password,
    database: dbConfig.database,
    multipleStatements: true
});

module.exports = db;
```

It seems that when i use now "db.query(....)" the mysql connection and release of that connection is done automatically.

So, it should resolve my issue but i don't know if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should i use pool connections instead?

Yes you should. [Pooling](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) is supported out-of-the-box with the mysql module.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  // should actually use an error-first callback to propagate the error, but anyway...
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

You're not supposed to know how pooling works. It's *abstracted* from you. All you need to do is use `pool` to dispatch queries. How it works internally is not something you're required to understand.

What you should pay attention to is the `connectionLimit` configuration option. This should match your MySQL server connection limit (minus one, in case you want to connect to it yourself while your application is running), otherwise you'll get ["too many connections"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) errors.  The default connection limit for MySQL is 100, so I'd suggest you set `connectionLimit` to `99`.

> Because if i keep only one connection it means that two users can't query the database in the same time?

Without pooling, you can't serve multiple user requests in-parallel. It's a *must* have for any non-hobby, data-driven application.

Now, if you really want to know how connection pooling works, this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) sums it up pretty nicely.

> In software engineering, a connection pool is a cache of database connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when future requests to the database are required. Connection pools are used to enhance the performance of executing commands on a database. Opening and maintaining a database connection for each user, especially requests made to a dynamic database-driven website application, is costly and wastes resources. In connection pooling, after a connection is created, it is placed in the pool and it is used again so that a new connection does not have to be established. If all the connections are being used, a new connection is made and is added to the pool. Connection pooling also cuts down on the amount of time a user must wait to establish a connection to the database.

Comment: I'm doing connection pooling but eventually I still run out of connections.  I was hoping mysql/mariadb would handle the "retries" but apparently not.  Is that really something my code should handle?

Comment: @RioBautista What do you mean by "retries"?

Comment: I was hoping mysql/mariadb or the drivers, could put the commands on queue if no connection is available and "retry" to execute them when a connection becomes available.